# Bigquery if condition for selecting reference table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables : Table_A and Table_B
I also have a parameter {{param.age}}

I would like to check the age, if it is 15 select * from Table_A otherwise select * from table_B.

I came up with this solution which is not working:

```
SELECT
  CASE 3
    WHEN 3 THEN ( SELECT * FROM `Table_A`)
  ELSE
  (SELECT * FROM `Table_B`)
END
```

I get this error: scalar subquery cannot have more than one column ...
I am sure there is an easy straightforward solution for this which I can not find.

Sudo code:

```
If parameter = x
Then SELECT * FROM Table_A
Else SELECT * FROM Table_B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the two queries have the same columns, you can do:

```
select *
from table_A
where parameter = x
union all
select *
from table_B
where parameter <> x;
```

If the two tables do not have the same columns, I would question what you want to do.  A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns.  Which columns do you want?  If the common columns between the two tables, then select them explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, two tables have same columns. Your solution works.